# Compiling PHP4.4 with MySQL 5 support

Tags: php, mysql, php4

I'm trying to support a rickety old system until the new intranet is built. The previous programmer somehow got PHP4 and MySQL 5 to work together by doing [option 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html) and I need to do the same to make a dev environment so I can stop messing directly with the live server.

I currently have a test server running PHP4 and I can't connect to my test DB or live DB because both are MySQL 5. Google is failing me because the easiest route seems to be to change the password to use

Can I get any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is tangled up with getting PHP to use the correct C client library for MySQL. It is possible but it takes you into the realms of libmysqlclient*.so and your package manager. The only advice I can give is that you will probably want a version newer than (I think) 12. You may need to recompile PHP for it to link against the newer library.

For the test DB, there is nothing stopping you changing the password. I wouldn't want the *test* app talking to the *live* DB, though (I'd use a CLI client to rummage in the live DB, not the test app). However the old password format will work seamlessly with the newer client, so that may be a solution for the moment.